# Editor Add-on receive webhook POST from third party service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-apps-script-addon

I have developed an internal editor add-on for Google Sheets for my school district. I am trying to integrate it with a third-party API that can send POST webhooks. Is there a way that I could receive the webhooks to my editor add-on for each user? As I understand it, I would need to receive the POST data through some other means (e.g. a dedicated spreadsheet with a doPost function), and have my editor add-on poll the source I'm receiving to. Things get hairy, though, because the data will 1) will require me to be a middleman for the data (which people might not be happy about), and 2) be an aggregate of all users of the add-on, which I'd then have to parse and distribute to users.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The user would need to create their own Apps Script file/project in their account, and publish it, and configure the API service to call their Web App.  That would mean more "set up" for the user.  You could program something that would create an Apps Script file in their account, but that would require the user giving your script access to create Apps Script files in their Google Drive.  So, no matter how you look at this, the user would need to be willing and able to do the set up, and configuration, or put a lot of trust in some app to access their account.

Comment: Yeah - that's pretty much what I was thinking. Unfortunately this is an add-on for teachers, and this solution would probably be way to hard for 99% of them to implement. Alas, back to the drawing board. Thanks.